# Need Help Removing Whitespace From Div

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath, nodes

I am new to DOM parsing, but I got most of this figured out. I'm just having trouble removing nbsp; from a div.

Here's my PHP:

```
    function parseDOM($url) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $movies = array();
        foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="mshow"]') as $movie) {
            $item = array();
            $links = $xpath->query('.//a', $movie);
            $item['trailer'] = $links->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
            $item['reviews'] = $links->item(1)->getAttribute('href');
            $item['link'] = $links->item(2)->getAttribute('href');
            $item['title'] = $links->item(2)->nodeValue;
            $item['rating'] = trim($xpath->query('.//strong/following-sibling::text()',
                $movie)->item(0)->nodeValue);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($xpath->query('.//div[@class="rsd"]', $movie) as $date) {
                $dates = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="rsd"]', $movie);
                $times = $xpath->query('.//div[@class="rst"]', $movie);
                $item['datetime'][] = $dates->item($i)->nodeValue . $times->item($i)->nodeValue;
                $i += 1;
            }
            $movies[] = $item;
        }
        return $movies;
    }

    $url = 'http://www.tribute.ca/showtimes/theatres/may-cinema-6/mayc5/?datefilter=-1';
    $movies = parseDOM($url);
    foreach ($movies as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['title'] . '<br>';
        echo $value['link'] . '<br>';
        echo $value['rating'] . '<br>';
        foreach ($value['datetime'] as $datetime) {
            echo $datetime . '<br>';
        }                     
    }
```

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
    <div class="rst" >6:45pm &nbsp;&nbsp;9:30pm &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Is there something I can add to the xpath query to achieve this? I did try adding strip_tags to `$times->item($i)->nodeValue`, but it's still printing out like: `Thu, May 01: 6:45pm Â Â 9:30pm Â Â`

Edit: `str_replace("\xc2\xa0", '', $times->item($i)->nodeValue);` seems to do the trick.

Comment: I suggest you try `normalize-space()`, e.g. `normalize-space(.//div[@class="rst"])`

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason it deletes the movie times completely:  ["datetime"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Thu, May 01: " }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$times->item($i)->nodeValue = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$times->item($i)->nodeValue);
```

it should delete every `&nbsp;`

---

### EDIT

your line :

```
$item['datetime'][] = $dates->item($i)->nodeValue . $times->item($i)->nodeValue;
```

become :

```
$item['datetime'][] = $dates->item($i)->nodeValue 
                        . str_replace("&nbsp;","",$times->item($i)->nodeValue);
```

---

### EDIT 2

if `str_replace` does not work, try with `str_ireplace`as suggested in comment.

If it still doesn't work, you can also try with :

```
preg_replace("#&nbsp;#","",$times->item($i)->nodeValue);
```

### EDIT 3

you may have an encoding problem. see `uft8_encode`

Or piggy solution :

```
str_replace("Â","",$times->item($i)->nodeValue);
```

Apolo

Comment: I'd suggest changing `str_replace` to the case-insensitive variant `str_ireplace`, just to be safe that it grabs all iterations of _&nbsp;_

Comment: Same result, still echoing: Thu, May 01: 6:45pm Â Â 9:30pm Â Â .

Comment: No luck. :( Maybe it's an encoding issue?

Comment: Surprisingly enough, str_replace for Â doesn't work either. If I add <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> to the top, it at least displays them as spaces, but I tried that with the first two solutions you provided, and it still displays 3 spaces.

Comment: This worked for me: str_replace("\xc2\xa0", '', $times->item($i)->nodeValue); 

Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: For a proper solution you could try with `preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $times->item($i)->nodeValue);` once everything is utf8, it should remove extra espaces.